# TCP server not receiving all data being sent

Tags: c#, xml, tcp, server, tcpserver

Attempting to setup a TCP server to grab data from a stream. Seems to be working, but only when the stream is small. Once I start sending large amounts of data, this fails, only returns a portion of the characters. Can anyone help me out here? Why am I only getting a portion of the data I am sending?

Flow of the server should be, receive ALL data, store into database (`RouteInboundXml()`) and begin listening for more incoming data.

```
private void ReceivePortMessages()
{
    string debug = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        Debug.Print(" >> Starting Server");
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        _TcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, TcpPort); ;
        Debug.Print(string.Format("{0}:{1}", ipAddress.ToString(), TcpPort.ToString()));
        _TcpListener.Start();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        do
        {
            try
            {
                _TcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Debug.Print(" >> Accept connection from client");
                NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream();
                int receivingBufferSize = (int)_TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize;
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[receivingBufferSize];
                int Read = 0;
                string dataFromClient = string.Empty;
                if (!sw.IsRunning)
                {
                    sw.Start();
                }
                Read = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, receivingBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));
                if (dataFromClient != string.Empty)
                {
                    XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                    debug = dataFromClient;
                    xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", dataFromClient));
                    XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
                    string rootName = root.FirstChild.Name;
                    RouteInboundXML(rootName, dataFromClient, sw);
                    sw.Restart();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                _TcpClient.Close();
                _TcpListener.Stop();
                ErrorLog.Write("XmlProcessing", ex.ToString() + "\r\n" + "DataFromClient: " + debug, "ReceivePortMessages()");
                return;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
        ErrorLog.Write("XmlProcessing", ex.ToString(), "ReceivePortMessages()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever checked the value of `dataFromClient` within debugging mode?

Comment: @Ordenador Yep, it's coming back as only about 70% of what I'm sending. The xml gets cut off midway through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting to receive an entire XML document - and *exactly* the XML document - each time you call `Stream.Read`. That's a really, really dangerous assumption.

The stream is a stream of data - while it'll be segmented into packets for transmission, you shouldn't expect to receive the data in the same number of `Read` calls as there were `Write` calls.

---

### Details for a single document per connection

If there's only one document per stream, you can probably simplify your code a lot *and* make it work properly. Just use the fact that there's an overload of `XmlDocument.Load` which accepts a stream:

```
using (var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    {
        doc.Load(stream);
    }
    // Use doc here
}
```

(If you can, I'd personally start using LINQ to XML instead, but that's a different matter.)

---

### Details for multiple documents

If you want multiple messages on a single TCP stream, you should implement some sort of "chunking" protocol. One good way of doing this is to split each message into a "header" and a "body" where the header may be as simple as "the number of bytes in the body", so you know how much to read. (Alternatively you could design the protocol for the header to contain other metadata.)

After reading the header, you read the body from the stream until either you've read as many bytes as were indicated in the header, or you reach the end of the stream (which would usually indicate an error). That may require multiple `Read` calls. *Then* you're in a suitable position to parse the data into an XML document - ideally without imposing your own binary/text decoding first, as not all XML is ASCII...

You *could* design your protocol in such a way that you just have a delimiter between messages instead - but that's generally much harder to implement, as it mixes "reading the data" and "understanding the data". If you can use the length-prefix scheme described above instead, that's much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon, I have no control over the xml coming in, so my hands are somewhat tied here. I am having to integrate with another system for a client that doesn't want to have to alter their setup. Have you covered anything particular on this off the top of your head that I cold look over? This is a particularly difficult concept for me (for some reason) and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how it all works.

Comment: @Volearix: Well are there definitely multiple XML documents coming on a single stream? It's more common to have a single document per connection if there's no length-prefix or similar. (Actually, I think I misread your code... if you're only expecting a single document, it's a lot simpler. Will edit...)

Comment: As far as I can tell from the spec it should only be one xml document per connection.

Comment: @Volearix: See my edit. Use the fact that the XML parser already knows how to handle streams...

Comment: `doc.Load(stream);` seems to just hang. Not throwing an error, but just hanging instead.

Comment: @Volearix: That suggests that the client isn't closing the stream that they're sending on. What does the documentation say about that? If the protocol hasn't been designed to either close the stream *or* specify how much data is in the document, it's still going to be painful to do this properly. It sounds like you might be best off talking to whoever is responsible for the client connecting to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78116/discussion-between-volearix-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code i have used in the past.
Works for me.

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port))
{
    var stm = client.GetStream();
    stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //Write some data to the stream

    byte[] resp = new byte[1024];
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    var bytes = 0;
    client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 200;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            bytes = stm.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length);
            memStream.Write(resp, 0, bytes);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // if the ReceiveTimeout is reached an IOException will be raised...
            // with an InnerException of type SocketException and ErrorCode 10060
            var socketExept = ex.InnerException as SocketException;
            if (socketExept == null || socketExept.ErrorCode != 10060)
            // if it's not the "expected" exception, let's not hide the error
            throw ex;
            // if it is the receive timeout, then reading ended
            bytes = 0;
        }
    } while (bytes > 0);

    return memStream.ToArray();
}
```